# Compare two columns from two different tables

Tags: oracle

TableA: Personal_info (Name,DOB,Fname,add,......)

TableB: Company_Info (Name,DOB,join_dt,Qual,sal....)

I want to compare these two tables in such a way that it displays different DOB with same name (Date of birth).

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should join the two tables on the Name field and not equal DOB:

```
SELECT Personal_Info.DOB, Company_Info.DOB, Name
FROM Personal_Info JOIN Company_Info ON Personal_Info.Name = Company_Info.Name 
AND Personal_Info.DOB != Company_Info.DOB
```